# How to prevent multiple entries of the exactly same parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where students can register for courses through enrollments. It is a has_many_through association.

However, I have an issue where a student can enroll for the same course multiple times.

```
#<StudentEnrollment course_code: "GST311", student_id: 1, created_at: "2019-11-20 17:52:22", updated_at: "2019-11-20 17:52:22">, 
#<StudentEnrollment course_code: "GST311", student_id: 1, created_at: "2019-11-20 17:53:14", updated_at: "2019-11-20 17:53:14">, 
#<StudentEnrollment course_code: "GST311", student_id: 1, created_at: "2019-11-20 18:00:33", updated_at: "2019-11-20 18:00:33">
```

Is there a proper way to check if the exact same enrollment exists and prevent it from being recreated?

Comment: Yes, set up a unique index on `[:student_id, :course_code]`. Then the database does all the work for you.

Comment: Do you mean like validates in the model?

Comment: Not validation. Index. Make a migration with `add_index :student_enrollments, [:student_id, :course_code], unique: true`. Validation is Rails doing checks before attempting to save. Unique index makes the database absolutely reject a record where the indexed columns are repeated. You can circumvent the former, but not the latter.

Comment: It passed this error ``SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: student_enrollments.student_id, student_enrollments.course_code``

Comment: As it should. If you got the error during migration, it means your database is already non-compliant. Wipe it (or at least delete the offending records) before trying the migration again. If you are getting the error when trying to insert a record, it's what should be happening: rescue it and show the user a custom error, or do whatever you want to do when the user messes up like that.

Comment: Oh... I see, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a scoped uniqueness validation here. The uniqueness validation allows us to specify uniqueness based on a combination of two or more attributes. So, a `course_code` + `student_id` combination could only exist once as per the scoped validation. It could be written as:

```
class StudentEnrollment <ApplicationRecord
  validates :student_id, uniqueness: { scope: :course_id }
end
```

This would ensure that a student-course combination can only be entered once into the database.

You could check the guide to uniqueness validations here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness . This handles uniqueness at an application level.

Additionally, as mentioned in the guide,

> Should you wish to create a database constraint to prevent possible violations of a uniqueness validation using the :scope option, you must create a unique index on both columns in your database.